# how to add legends from stat_summary and remove legends from the main plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I want to plot the values of df1 by two groups i.e. product and start_date and also plot a crossbar with the mean of df1(blue) and mean of df2(red) as in the attached diagram.

```
df1 <- data.frame(product = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D","D"), 
                  start_date =as.Date(c('2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06', '2020-02-07')),
                  value = c(15.71,17.37,19.93,14.28,15.85,10.5,8.58,5.62,5.19,5.44,4.6,7.04,6.29,3.3,20.35,27.92,23.07,12.83,22.28,21.32,31.46,34.82,23.68,29.11,14.48,25.2,16.91,27.79))

df2 <- data.frame(product = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D"), 
                  start_date =as.Date(c('2019-07-09', '2019-07-10', '2019-07-11', '2019-07-12', '2019-07-13', '2019-07-14')),
                  value = c(9.06,10.74,14.64,7.67,8.72,11.21,4.76,4.53,3.81,4.32,3.95,5.2,20.36,21.17,19.51,16.25,17.93,16.94,14.51,14.65,23.28,10.84,16.71,12.48))
```

## PLOT GRAPH

```
graph1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(
    y = value, x = product, fill = product, color = factor(start_date))) +
  geom_col(data = df1, stat = "identity",position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7, inherit.aes = TRUE, size = 0) + 
  xlab("Product") + ylab("Values")  + ylim(c(0,40)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#008FCC", "#FFAA00", "#E60076", "#B00000")) +
  stat_summary(data = df1, aes(x = factor(product),y = value),fun = "mean",geom = "crossbar", color = "blue", size = 1, width = 0.8, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(data = df2, aes(x = factor(product),y = value),fun = "mean",geom = "crossbar", color = "red", size = 1, width = 0.8, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Is there any way to remove the borders of the bar plots and add legend of the two crossbars at the top right corner of the plot ?
[image]

Additionally I would like to know if is there a way to add the just the "date" from df1 below each bar in the plot ?

Comment: Hi, are you sure the means in your question are correct? The values on the plots seem ok; `df1 %>% group_by(product) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value))
df2 %>% group_by(product) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value))`

Comment: @monkeytennis Thanks for your feedback, it's updated now, can you please address the other part of the question to add legends from only the stat_summary plot ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question about adjusting the plot has multiple parts.  To summarize a few points:

- Change from `color=factor(start_date)` to `group=` to remove the color around bars, but maintain the separation of individual bars by start_date
- Use `theme(legend.position=...` and specify precise placement of legend within plot area.  Use `theme(legend.direction='horizontal')` too when appropriate.
- Add `color=` attribute into the `stat_summary(geom='crossbar'...)` calls in order to "add" them both to a legend, then use `scale_color_manual` to specify color if you don't like the default.
- *Minor suggestion:* Use `ylim(X,Y)` instead of `ylim(c(X,Y))`.  It's not necessary to put the limits into a vector, since `ylim` can accept that instead and it's simpler.  Note that it still works either way, so that's why this point is minor.
- You don't need the `data=df1` for the first `stat_summary` call, since it's the default mapping based on the `data=` value set in `ggplot(...`.  You still need the `y=` value though, since it is required.

Here's the adjusted code from implementing the notes above:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(y = value, x = product, fill = product, group = factor(start_date))) +
    geom_col(data = df1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
        width = 0.7, inherit.aes = TRUE, size = 0) +
    xlab("Product") + ylab("Values") + ylim(0,60) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#008FCC", "#FFAA00", "#E60076", "#B00000")) +
    stat_summary(aes(x = factor(product), y=value, color='mean1'),
        fun = "mean", geom = "crossbar",
        size = 1, width = 0.8, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    stat_summary(data = df2, aes(x = factor(product),y=value, color='mean2'),
        fun = "mean", geom = "crossbar",
        size = 1, width = 0.8, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    theme(legend.position=c(0.75,0.8), legend.direction = 'horizontal') +
    scale_color_manual(values=c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

**Explanation:** The point of changing to `group=factor(start_date)` is so that you maintain the splitting of bars among the different products--a concept known as "dodging".  Since your original call to `color=` was in the `aes(`, it created a legend item and the `geom_col` used this for dodging, since the other aesthetics were already mapped to `x` and `y`, and the `fill=` aesthetic was being applied.  If you remove `color=`, you get one bar for each product.  Even if you specify `position='dodge'`, `geom_col` would not dodge them because there's no information about how to do that.  That's why you include the `group=` aesthetic--to give `geom_col` information on how it should be dodging.

You use `aes(...` to indicate to `ggplot` which legends to create.  If the aesthetic is mapped to `x` or `y`, it just uses that for plotting.  `group=` aesthetics are used for dodging and other group attributes, but basically any other aesthetics (`size`, `shape`, `color`, `fill`, `linetype`... etc etc) are used to create legends.  If we specify both `stat_summary` calls to include a `color` aesthetic, a legend will be created that is combined.  The problem here is that there is no column in the dataset (because you have two) to use for mapping to color, so we create one by naming a character ("mean1" and "mean2").

Final point:  It might be easier to plot this if you combine your datasets.  You may still want to indicate where they came from, so something like this works:

```
df1$origin_df <- 'df1'
df2$origin_df <- 'df2'
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Then plot with `df` and not `df1`.  You can then use one `stat_summary` call where you specify `color=origin_df`.

Comment: Thanks for that great code and explanation, it was perfect.

Comment: Additionally I would like to know if is there a way to add the just the "date" from df1 below each bar in the plot ?